# What different between Binary Format and XML format for create snapshot of Acumatica version 5.30.1672?

Tags: customization, acumatica

For the help they said: 
Binary: The exported data is saved in a collection of .adb files.
XML: The exported data is saved in a collection of .xml files.
But I'm not sure about this.

Comment: What are you not sure about? Binary saves the exported data in binary files with .adb extensions. XML saves the exported data in XML format. There's not really a more clear explanation.

Comment: It seems different when I create snapshot with Binary the size is 0.23MB but with XML size is 0.26MB. So how different between both of them?

Comment: They're different formats. They're not going to be the same size.

Comment: Anyways, They're created in two different type of snapshots so maybe they should be used in other ways too right? Sorry if my question unclear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML format was only recently added to Acumatica. The main benefit of XML over binary is that it can be stored in version controlled and easily compared. Binary on the other hand is more compact. This feature was mostly added for the benefit of OEMs and ISVs that are localizing and adapting the product for their respective markets and need easy ability to make changes to the default system data when provisioning new companies.

Comment: Anyways, is it problem if I export as XML or Binary that not effect to my system right?

Comment: It is not a problem to use one or the other